# Split the following list into 4 elements using TCL

Tags: string, list, split, tcl

How Do I split the following list into 4 elements using TCL

W.1.Agg-251::ethernet17/24 Z.1.Acc-2::ethernet17/1

I tried as below , But the middle two elements looks to be sticking together ,

set c [split $c ::]
{\ W.1.Agg-251 {} {ethernet17/24 Z.1.Acc-2} {} ethernet17/1}

Update:

The solution provided below does work if I pass the list as it is , but when i pass it as a variable liek below , again I see the middle elements are stuck together .

Like so :

```
 set list2 [lindex $list 0]
```

o/p==>     W.1.Agg-251::ethernet17/24 Z.1.Acc-2::ethernet17/1

```
 set list3 [split [string map {:: :} $list2] ":" ]
```

o/p==>     { W.1.Agg-251} {ethernet17/24 Z.1.Acc-2} ethernet17/1

Comment: Foo , That is how the input list is , My desired out put is another list of four elements {{W.1.Agg-251 }{ethernet17/24}{ Z.1.Acc-2}{ethernet17/1} }

Comment: With regard to your update: you are failing to split the middle element because you only passed a colon to split on. In my example I set the split chars collection to a colon and a space (eg: ": "). So it splits on both colons and spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to replace "::" with a space " ":

```
set list2 [string map {"::" " "} $list]
```

Verify:

```
foreach token $list2 { puts ">$token<" }
```

Output:

```
>W.1.Agg-251<
>ethernet17/24<
>Z.1.Acc-2<
>ethernet17/1<
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to split is not a string to split on but a set of characters that may be used for splitting. Note the following example:

```
% split {a::b::c::d} ::
a {} b {} c {} d
% split {a::b::c::d} :
a {} b {} c {} d
```

What you are trying to do seems to be to split on "::" and space. You should squash the :: sequence first, then split as below:

```
% split [string map {:: :} {W.1.Agg-251::ethernet17/24 Z.1.Acc-2::ethernet17/1}] ": "
W.1.Agg-251 ethernet17/24 Z.1.Acc-2 ethernet17/1
```

Comment: In case there happen to be valid single colons in the fields, use string map to change double colon to space, then split with default splitchars: `set result [split [string map {:: " "} $c]]`

Answer (score 0):

You said 4 elements, but I only see 3 elements (two :: pairs).  Are you sure the space between 24 and Z should not be a :: instead?

Comment: Foo , That is how the input list is , My desired out put is another list of four elements  {{W.1.Agg-251 }{ethernet17/24}{ Z.1.Acc-2}{ethernet17/1} }